# Trying to bind several form fields to one model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Maybe what am i asking is totally dumb, but i cannot find any examples where several form fields are bind to one (complex) property of the model.

### extract from my unit test

```cs
...
            var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent(formDataBoundary)
            {
                { new StringContent("0123456789"), "did" },
                { new StringContent("A"), "connectionStatus" },
                { new StringContent("Access Only 2432/160"), "descriptionOffer" },
                { new StringContent("ADSN4DSL"), "codeOffer" },
                { new StringContent("NORMAL"), "supportLevel" },
                { new StringContent("Entreprise TEST"), "finalCustomerDenomination" },
                { new StringContent("RUE"), "finalCustomerStreetCode" },
                { new StringContent("du Test"), "finalCustomerStreetName" },
                { new StringContent("45"), "finalCustomerStreetNumber" },
                { new StringContent("69389"), "finalCustomerCityCode" },
                { new StringContent("69009"), "finalCustomerCityPostalCode" },
                { new StringContent("Lyon 9e"), "finalCustomerCityName" },
                { new StringContent("TestCustomer"), "finalCustomerContactName" },
                { new StringContent("0987654321"), "finalCustomerContactPhoneNumber" },
                { new StringContent("TestOperator"), "operatorContactName" },
                { new StringContent("0512346789"), "operatorContactPhoneNumber" },
                { new StringContent("Un commentaire opérateur"), "operatorComment" },
                { new StringContent("Une note..."), "note" },
            };

            var response = await client
                .PostAsync(CREATION_URL, formData)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
...
```

### extract from my controller

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(
            [FromForm] CreationOrderInput input)
{
...
```

### extract from my input model

```cs
    public sealed class CreationOrderInput
    {
        public FrenchPhoneNumber Did { get; set; }
        public Address FinalCustomerAddress { get; set; }
...
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public virtual NonEmptyString? Designation { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString StreetLabel { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString? StreetCode { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString? StreetNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString? Cluster { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString? Building { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString? Stair { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString? Floor { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString? Door { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString? Logo { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString? CityCode { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString CityPostalCode { get; set; }
        public virtual NonEmptyString CityName { get; set; }
    }
```

Basically, i'm trying to make a address *binder* to bind `finalCustomerXXX` to several properties of `Address`, but `IModelBinder.BindModelAsync` seems rather obscure to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

## Update

I've no control over the POST and the field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to pass a complex object to the post method.

Since the fields of the class you provide are inconsistent with some of the field names provided in MultipartFormDataContent, *I will simplify your class to make the code more clear*.

> Basically, i'm trying to make a address binder to bind
> finalCustomerXXX to several properties of Address

If you want to bind the fields under the corresponding class in the form of `finalCustomerXXX`, you must first make sure that the content before `XXX` is the **field name** of the corresponding class, and **they need to be separated by dots(.), or put `XXX` in square bracketswhich([])**  like follow:

```
 FinalCustomerAddress.XXX or FinalCustomerAddress[XXX]
```

Here `FinalCustomerAddress` is the field name of `Address` type in `CreationOrderInput` class, and `XXX` is the field name of `Address` class like CityCode.

The following is a complete case, please refer to it：

```
public sealed class CreationOrderInput
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public FrenchPhoneNumber Did { get; set; }
    public Address FinalCustomerAddress { get; set; }
}

public class FrenchPhoneNumber
{
    public string number { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public virtual NonEmptyString? CityCode { get; set; }
    public virtual NonEmptyString CityPostalCode { get; set; }
    public virtual NonEmptyString CityName { get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```
  var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent(formDataBoundary)
        {
            { new StringContent("Lisa"), "Name" },
            { new StringContent("0123456789"), "Did[number]" }, 
            { new StringContent("69389"), "FinalCustomerAddress[CityCode]" },
            { new StringContent("69009"), "FinalCustomerAddress[CityPostalCode]" },
            { new StringContent("Lyon 9e"), "FinalCustomerAddress[CityName]" },
              //or
             //{ new StringContent("0123456789"), "Did.number" },
             //{ new StringContent("69389"), "FinalCustomerAddress.CityCode" },
             //{ new StringContent("69009"), "FinalCustomerAddress.CityPostalCode" },
             //{ new StringContent("Lyon 9e"), "FinalCustomerAddress.CityName" },
        };
             var response = await client
            .PostAsync(CREATION_URL, formData)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that i have no control over the post form data fields, name or value. Maybe, the easy way is to flatten the `Address` into `CreationOrderInput` and make property names match form data field names.